# Do I need change anything on my regular expression?

Tags: regex, xsd

I want to transfer a fixed length text to XML, and I use RegEx to do it.
In position 36 of each line of the text file is about 'User's initial' which requires 1 alphanumeric. but sometime it is blank. 
So I use RegEx pattern like [a-zA-Z\s]{1} which is good, it either matches 1 alphanumeric or blank.
But when I do the validation using schema, the schema says my RegEx doesn't match with his \p{L}{1} which means it can only be letter.
So what should I do on my RegEx? or they have to change either text file pattern or change schema.
Here is my code example:

```
Dim linePattern2 As New Regex("^(?<type_code>\d{3})(?<snm>[a-zA-Z0-9\s.\']{20})(?<gvn_nm>[a-zA-Z0-9\s.\']{12})(?<init>[\p{L} ]{1})(?<sin>\d{9})(?<rcpnt_bn>[a-zA-Z0-9\s.\']{15})(?<l1_nm>[a-zA-Z0-9\s.\']{30})(?<l2_nm>[a-zA-Z0-9\s.\']{30})")
    Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()
    settings.Indent = True
    Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(xmlOutput, settings)
        writer.WriteStartDocument()
        writer.WriteStartElement("Submission")
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", Nothing, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", Nothing, "c:\schema\layout-topologie.xsd")

        writer.WriteStartElement("Return")
        writer.WriteStartElement("T4A")
        Using reader As New StreamReader(textInput)
            While Not reader.EndOfStream

                    Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
                    Dim match2 As Match = linePattern2.Match(line)
                    If match2.Success Then
                        writer.WriteStartElement("T4ASlip")

                        writer.WriteStartElement("RCPNT_NM")
                        writer.WriteElementString("snm", match2.Groups("snm").Value)
                        writer.WriteElementString("gvn_nm", match2.Groups("gvn_nm").Value)
                        writer.WriteElementString("init", match2.Groups("init").Value)
                        writer.WriteEndElement()

                        writer.WriteElementString("sin", match2.Groups("sin").Value)
                        writer.WriteElementString("rcpnt_bn", match2.Groups("rcpnt_bn").Value)
                        End If
            End While
        End Using
        writer.WriteEndElement()
        writer.WriteEndElement()
        writer.WriteEndElement()
        writer.WriteEndDocument()
    End Using
```

Here is the part of text file:

```
100AASERUDE            RUSSELL ALAN 663345678000000000000000
```

The schema validation error is:

'init': value ' ' does not match regular expression facet '\p{L}{1}'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can we see some samples of input and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the regex you want:

```
[\p{L} ]
```

- `\p{L}` matches **any** letter, not just the ASCII letters (`[a-zA-Z]`).  It includes accented ASCII letters like `Ä` and `ñ`, plus "letters" from other scripts and writing systems like Greek, Cyrillic, Arabic, Chinese... any letter known to Unicode.
- Since your text format is fixed-length, I assume a missing initial is represented by a space, not an empty string as one would usually expect.  I used a literal space, but you can switch back to `\s` if you really want to allow TAB, linefeed, or other whitespace characters.
- The `{1}` in your regexes serves no purpose.  If you want to make sure only one character is allowed, you *usually* add anchors, like this: `^[\p{L} ]$`.  But that isn't necessary in XML Schema, where all regexes are always anchored at both ends.

Comment: Alan Moore, I just tried your regex, it still same thing. Actually there is no big different between yours and mine. Thanks!

Comment: Then we need more information.  Without samples of the data and your code, we won't be able to help you.  Please edit your original question and add the information there.